# Setting attribute of NSManagedObject is blocking the iPad UI' in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

Firstly, I have found a couple of related questions on the issue with links pasted below, but none have really helped me solve the problem:

[iPhone CoreData properties: changes to managedObjects are too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595695/iphone-coredata-properties-changes-to-managedobjects-are-too-slow)

[iOS CoreData: NSFetchedResultsController performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796433/ios-coredata-nsfetchedresultscontroller-performances)

I have a tableview with approximately 5,000 rows that is currently being managed by a fetched results controller.

Each row displays basic attributes of a Document entity, and also includes a button for users to tag a specific Document as favourite. Admittedly, the Document entity has relationships with a few different entities and the underlying SQLite database is largeish (~20mb).

Fetching the attributes for each row is relatively quick and the table view performs quite well with that many items. Saving changes is not an issue either.

My problem arises when I try to change the isFavourite (BOOL) attribute of my Document entity. This attribute gets set / updated on a button touch up inside event with:

```
[document setIsFavourite:[NSNumber numberWithBool:![document isFavourite]]]
```

The issue here is that on every tap of the Favourite button, this particular line of code blocks the UI for ~1-2 secs which is obviously not ideal.

I have tried marking the isFavourite attribute as indexed, as well as increasing the fetch batch size and finally creating a cache for the NSFetchedResultsController but nothing seems to help with performance.

The only way that I managed to avoid the UI lock was to perform the attribute setting on a background thread, but this involves creating a new context, registering for notifications and merging changes when the context is saved. In this case another issue comes up, as when I respond to the save notification with merge changes, my fetched results controller seems to get confused and the changed row is removed from my tableview automatically, and the only way to get it back is to do a [tableview reloadData].

Has anyone else experience a similar problem and is there anything else I could try to fix it?

Many thanks in advance,

Rog

Comment: How did you confirm that that particular line causes the hang?

Comment: Instruments is your friend. If that line really is the offender I would use instruments to see what kvo observer is causing you to stall.

Comment: @ImHuntingWabbits I've tried instruments but it won't let me run any of the core data templates on iOS for some reason (it says it is not compatible). Is there any other way?

Comment: You don't need to run one of the CoreData templates, just use a time profiler to see what's causing your slowdown after the UI responds to the tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line shouldn't cause a hang because nothing has to be fetched. You already have the document object in memory and you are changing just a single attribute of that object also in memory.

I can think of only two reasons why such a line would cause a hang.

First, you have a custom accessor for `setIsFavourite:` that triggers side effects which drive faulting and fetches. E.g. You have custom logic that triggers when the `isFavourite` attribute changes that triggers a fetched property.

I lean towards this explanation because you are using the old reference form instead of:

```
document.isFavourite=[NSNumber numberWithBool:![document isFavourite]];
```

If you created the class of the `document` object by hand, check that you used `@dynamic` instead of `@synthesize` for the properties. The later will not work well with NSManagedObject subclasses.

Secondly, you have validation set on the attribute that triggers a similar cascade e.g. the validation has to check a property in another object.

I am rather dubious that the line of code is actually the source of the problem.

Comment: after further investigation, I think you are probably right that this particular line is not really the cause of my problem but it is the one that triggers it. I believe that this attribute value change is triggering the fetched results controller / tableview update methods which in this case is completely unnecessary so I am wondering if it is possible to prevent this from happening somehow (for a particular attribute)? I did a test with a simple fetch request instead and it works perfectly (I update the UI manually as required).

Comment: Check your code in `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` and see what happens when you make the change. Do you have any custom accessors?

Comment: yes as expected that switch is getting triggered when the attribute changes, but the funny thing is that all it is doing is making a call to `configureCell:atIndexPath:` which essentially updates the UI to show that item has been marked as favourite. I don't get why it would be such an expensive task to the point of locking the UI for a bit?

Comment: It shouldn't. Its a very common task. The answer is in the code details. You could use Instruments to profile the code or if your not familiar with instruments, just log a time stamp at the begining and end of the suspected methods. That will tell you exactly which method is bogging. Then you can narrow it down to the line.

Comment: thanks again for your help, I'll see how I go and post my findings along the way.